# GLSL textures that has more than 4 components

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, glsl

I have a little problem with opengl, I have a 3d map so I would like to apply several textures.

I have created a shader with textures but the problem when using rgba is that I am blocked only has 4 components text maximum

```
uniform sampler2D detail_tex1;
uniform sampler2D detail_tex2;
uniform sampler2D detail_tex3;
uniform sampler2D detail_tex4;
uniform sampler2D detail_tex5;
uniform sampler2D attribute_tex;

  vec3 diffuse = texture(detail_tex1, terrain_uv * 16.0).rgb * texture(attribute_tex, terrain_uv).r;
  diffuse += texture(detail_tex2, terrain_uv * 16.0).rgb * texture(attribute_tex, terrain_uv).g;
  diffuse += texture(detail_tex3, terrain_uv * 16.0).rgb * texture(attribute_tex, terrain_uv).b;
  diffuse += texture(detail_tex4, terrain_uv * 16.0).rgb * texture(attribute_tex, terrain_uv).a;
```

Textures only have 4 components, so I can only do this for 4 textures. My question is how do I overcome this constraint?

i share complete code, i use panda3d engine in python
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VjpEnEktwGfw6rZyE6nGDkdj-8gZF29Z/view

Comment: What hardware are you using that "only has 4 text maximum"?

Comment: i have 4 texture because rgb have 4 channels R,G,B and A (transparent)
i want use other system that rgb for have more channels

Comment: you'd use a 3D texture

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: ... That's not what he's talking about.

Comment: @NicolBolas is it not? sounds like he wants `attribute_text` to have more than 4 components.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: And 3D textures don't have more *components*. They're still RGBA values. They have more *texture coordinates*, but that's different from components.

Comment: @NicolBolas right, but the 3rd dimension would represent the components, like `texture(attribute_tex, vec3(terrain_uv, 4)).r` to get the 5th value (built using just `GL_RED`)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: That's not how 3D textures work. At all. The 3rd dimension works exactly the same as the other 2. So if `terrain_uv` are normalized texture coordinates, so is the 3rd one. You're talking about a 2D array texture.

Comment: i share my full code, my glsl is in file terrain.frag.glsl
yes it's for 3D world map
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VjpEnEktwGfw6rZyE6nGDkdj-8gZF29Z/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting each attribute in a separate channel of the same texture, create `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` with a single-channel internal format (such as `GL_R8` or `GL_R16F`), put each attribute in a separate array layer, and put each of your detail textures into a layer of another array texture. You can then use a shader similar to this one:

```
uniform sampler2DArray detail_array;
uniform sampler2DArray attribute_array;
uniform uint texture_count;
...
vec3 diffuse(0.0);
for (uint i = 0; i < texture_count; ++i) {
    diffuse += texture(detail_array, vec3(terrain_uv * 16.0, i)).rgb *
        texture(attribute_array, vec3(terrain_uv, i)).r;
}
```

If you need to read from different textures for different meshes, you can pass an array of integers identifying which textures should be read.

Note that sampling this many textures per pixel is probably inefficient for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Textures only have 4 components, period. There's no getting around that. The only question is how best to deal with it.

For example, the obvious solution is to use multiple textures to control the blending of the various layers. `attribute_tex1` would have the first 4 components, `attribute_tex2` would have the second 4, and so forth. You just access them with the same texture coordinates.

If you want to avoid the overhead of having multiple textures, you can try to pack your data into a single texture. This requires some degree of knowledge of exactly what these values are. For example, do you really need *every possible* combination of these 5 textures? Or are you really just blending between two "neighboring" textures? That is, does a particular pixel blend between 1&2, and another between 2&3, but none blend between 1&3?

If that's the case, then your blending data needs only to be the index of the first texture and the blend factor for that texture. The second index is just the first index +1, and the second blend factor is just 1.0 - the first blend factor.

And at this point, you don't really need a bunch of individual textures. What you need is a 2D [*array* texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture). I pick an array texture here rather than a 3D texture because you probably still want mipmapping to work correctly. In a 3D texture, lower mipmaps would not blend correctly.

Your `attribute_tex` would use the `GL_RG8UI` format, which means it stores unsigned integer data. The `r` component is the first index, and the `g` component is the first blend factor, where 0 means to use the full value of the second, and 255 means the full value of the first.

Your `detail_tex#` textures would become a single `sampler2DArray` texture, where each of the original images become layers in the texture. Layer 0 corresponds to `detail_tex1`, and so forth.

So your code becomes this:

```
uniform sampler2DArray detail_textures;
uniform usampler2D attribute_tex; //Must be `u` to designate that it's an unsigned integer texture.

...

vec2 blend_factors = texture(attribute_tex, terrain_uv).rg;
vec4 tex_first = texture(detail_textures, vec3(terrain_uv, blend_factors.r);
vec4 tex_second = texture(detail_textures, vec3(terrain_uv, blend_factors.r + 1);
diffuse = mix(tex_first, tex_second, blend_factors.g / 255.0f);
```

Comment: i share my full code, my glsl is in file terrain.frag.glsl it's for 3D world map  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VjpEnEktwGfw6rZyE6nGDkdj-8gZF29Z/view 
the problem in your solution is that don't know when there will be for example grass or mountain or forest

Comment: @ilapasle: I offered two solutions. The general one, and a more specific one.

Comment: ok, in your example if i want create third texture i add this :
vec4 tex_third = texture(detail_textures, vec3(terrain_uv, blend_factors.r + 2);
diffuse = mix(tex_first, tex_second, tex_third, blend_factors.g / 255.0f);

? i have last question what is color of blend_factors.r + 1 and blend_factors.r + 2 ?